# Getting empty output with Erase tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, erase

I'm looking to isolate the parts of two hexagon feature classes that overlap:

[image]

[image]

I thought that I could use the Overlay > Erase tool to do this. The "input feature" would be the first image, and the "erase feature" would be the second image.

When I run the tool, I get an empty feature class (and the error message "empty output generated").

Both of my feature classes have identical coordinate systems. I also ran the Check Geometry tool on both of them and it did not return any results. Why is this not returning the triangle of overlapping feature classes that I would expect?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Erase removes the overlap. You need to reverse your inputs or perhaps use Intersect to return the overlap

Comment: Erase erases features.  Intersect returns the overlaps.  Union returns all parts split at intersecting boundaries.  To isolate the features that overlap, you need to run the intersect tool